# Game of life not resetting properly

Tags: java, timer, timertask

I'm trying to make my version of game of life reset when a reset button is clicked but I have an issue.
After clicking the button, everything successfully reset but not the main `Jpanel` where we see the generations moving.
I have two `JLabel`, one showing the number of the current generation and the other showing the amount of alive cells in that generation. They are both reseted successfully but the main `JPanel` just freezes and I cannot see the animation anymore.

GameOfLife class:

```
public class GameOfLife extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

private static class GameStep extends TimerTask {
    static GameOfLife life = new GameOfLife();

    @Override
    public void run() {
        updateLabels();
    }
}

static JLabel aliveLabel = new JLabel("Alive:");
static JLabel GenerationLabel = new JLabel("Generation #");
static CellGrid body = new CellGrid();
static JPanel header = new JPanel();
static int genNumber = 1;
static JButton PlayToggleButton = new JButton("pause");
static JButton ResetButton = new JButton("reset");
static Boolean isPaused = false;
static GameStep game = new GameStep();
static Timer timer = new Timer();


public GameOfLife() {
    super("Game of life");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(700, 660);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    GenerationLabel.setName("GenerationLabel");
    aliveLabel.setName("aliveLabel");
    PlayToggleButton.setName("PlayToggleButton");
    ResetButton.setName("ResetButton");

    PlayToggleButton.addActionListener(this);
    ResetButton.addActionListener(this);

    PlayToggleButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon(play));
    ResetButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon(reset));

    PlayToggleButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40,30));
    ResetButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40,30));

    header.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    header.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, this.getHeight()));
    header.add(PlayToggleButton);
    header.add(ResetButton);
    header.add(GenerationLabel);
    header.add(aliveLabel);

    body.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    body.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, this.getHeight()));

    add(header, BorderLayout.WEST);
    add(body, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    setVisible(true);

}

public static void updateLabels(){
    body.run();
    GenerationLabel.setText("Generation #"+ genNumber++);
    aliveLabel.setText("Alive: "+ body.totalAlive());
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if(e.getActionCommand().equals("pause")){
        pauseResume();
    }
    else if(e.getActionCommand().equals("reset")){
        reset();
    }
}

static void loopStep(){
    timer.schedule(game, 0,1000);
}

static void pauseResume() {

    if(!isPaused){
        isPaused = true;
        timer.cancel();
    }
    else{
        isPaused = false;
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new GameStep(), 0,1000);
    }
}
static void reset() {
    timer.cancel();
    isPaused = false;

    genNumber = 1;
    header = new JPanel();
    body = new CellGrid();
    body.repaint();

    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new GameStep(), 0,1000);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   loopStep();
}
}
```

CellGrid class:

```
public class CellGrid extends JPanel implements Runnable{
private static final int ROWS = 60;
private static final int COLS = 60;
private static final int CELL_WIDTH = 10;
private static Cell[][] cellGrid = new Cell[ROWS][COLS];

public CellGrid() {
    for (int row = 0; row < cellGrid.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < cellGrid[row].length; col++) {
            int x = col * CELL_WIDTH;
            int y = row * CELL_WIDTH;
            cellGrid[row][col] = new Cell(x, y, CELL_WIDTH);

            if (new Random().nextBoolean()) {
                cellGrid[row][col].setAlive(true);
            } else {
                cellGrid[row][col].setAlive(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
public int totalAlive(){
    int totalAlive = 0;
    for (Cell[] cells : cellGrid) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cellGrid.length; j++) {
            if (cells[j].isAlive())
                totalAlive++;
        }
    }
    return totalAlive;
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    for (Cell[] cellRow : cellGrid) {
        for (Cell cell : cellRow) {
            cell.draw(g2);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {
    cellGrid = new GenerationMaker4().nextGeneration(cellGrid);
    repaint();
}
}
```

any idea why it's happening ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `reset()` method:

```
static void reset() {
    timer.cancel();
    isPaused = false;

    genNumber = 1;
    header = new JPanel();
    body = new CellGrid();
    body.repaint();

    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new GameStep(), 0,1000);
}
```

The problem is a common newbie mistake -- you think that changing a variable reference will change the prior object that the variable originally referenced.

Specifically, you have `body = new CellGrid();` and what this does is have the body variable refer to a new CellGrid object, but (and here is the important part), it *does nothing to the CellGrid object that is currently displayed in your GUI, that the body variable previously referred to.

Several alternative solutions:

- Add the new CellGrid object now referred to in the body variable to the GUI in the same BorderLayout position, covering the previous one
- Better still is to not create a new CellGrid object but instead to create a way to set the current CellGrid back to its initial state.

For example, perhaps if you changed CellGrid to...

```
public class CellGrid extends JPanel implements Runnable{
    private static final int ROWS = 60;
    private static final int COLS = 60;
    private static final int CELL_WIDTH = 10;
    private Cell[][] cellGrid = new Cell[ROWS][COLS]; // make this non-static

    public CellGrid() {
        reset();
    }

    public void reset() {   
        cellGrid = new Cell[ROWS][COLS];
        for (int row = 0; row < cellGrid.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < cellGrid[row].length; col++) {
                int x = col * CELL_WIDTH;
                int y = row * CELL_WIDTH;
                cellGrid[row][col] = new Cell(x, y, CELL_WIDTH);

                if (new Random().nextBoolean()) {
                    cellGrid[row][col].setAlive(true);
                } else {
                    cellGrid[row][col].setAlive(false);
                }
            }
        }
    }

// ..... more code below
```

Then all you need to do is to call `reset()` on the current CellGrid object, and then call `repaint()`.

Other issues:

- You grossly over-use the static modifier. Nothing in this program should be static, other than the main method, your constants, and that's it. This may not be important for this small program, but it will become important later when you try to do unit testing or extend or enhance this program, or add it to another larger program.
- You use `java.util.Timer` and `java.util.TimerTask` to run an animation loop in a Swing GUI program, and this is not safe to do, since these classes are not Swing thread-safe. Much better to use a `javax.swing.Timer` or "Swing Timer" in place of both of these classes to run the animation since this is thread-safe for this GUI library.

Comment: I just tried what you suggested about the CellGrid class and it worked. You have some very useful informations also, I'll take the time to read and make the appropriate changes. Thanks a lot !